# How to set .ini file in the server?

Tags: php, php-ini

For My PDF Generation I am using MPDF. But its not working in client's server. It shows no problem in my local system and my server. So I tried to change the max_execution_time, max_input_time, memory_limit in the ini file. But its not changing. When I used .htaccess it showed " For security reasons, mod_php is not used on this server. Use a php.ini file for php directives"..

I tried ini_set(), .user.ini file, php.ini file options. Is there any other way I can change the ini settings on the server?

Comment: What options are you trying to change? You can also use .htaccess http://davidwalsh.name/php-values-htaccess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding this specific line to .htaccess file reads the newly created php.ini file in that folder.

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .php
```